# Finding a function $f$ with the minimal $\|f'\|_1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

I was wondering about the following question, which I am sure the answer is known. I couldn't quite find it and I would appreciate if someone could tell me.

Suppose I have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$f(-1)=0$, $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$, and  $f(x) = 0$ if $|x|>1$. I was wondering what is the minimum possible value of  $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f'(x)| dx$ and what is $f$ that achieves it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Something is wrong, you asked for $f(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$, you probably meant $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. It is fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: Assuming $f\in C^1,$ we have $\int_{-1}^0f' = f(0)-f(1) = 1.$ Hence $\int_{-1}^0|f'| \ge 1.$ The same applies on $[0,1].$ Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb R}|f'| = \int_{-1}^1|f'| \ge 2.$$

Towards finding the minimum value: Let $f$ be any $C^1$ function satisfying the hypotheses that in addition is increasing on $[-1,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,1].$